# Evaluate $\binom{n}0-2\binom{n}1 + 3\binom{n}2 +···+(−1)^n (n+1) \binom{n}n$

Tags: combinatorics

Evaluate

$\binom{n}0-2\binom{n}1 + 3\binom{n}2 +···+(−1)^n(n+1)\binom{n}n$

which is the same as:

$\sum_{k=0}^n=(-1)^k(k+1)\binom{n}k$

**My attempt:**

Using the Binomial Theorem, we get:

$(1+x)^n=\binom{n}0+\binom{n}1x+\binom{n}2x^2+...+\binom{n}nx^n$

$(n+1)(1+x)^n = \binom{n}0+2\binom{n}1x+3\binom{n}2x^2+...+(n+1)\binom{n}nx^n$

Letting $x=-1$ we get:

$(n+1)(1-1)^n = \binom{n}0-2\binom{n}1+3\binom{n}2+...+(n+1)\binom{n}n(-1)^n$

Therefore,

$\binom{n}0-2\binom{n}1 + 3\binom{n}2 +···+(−1)^n(n+1)\binom{n}n$ = $(n+1)(0)^n=0$

or

$\sum_{k=0}^n=(-1)^k(k+1)\binom{n}k$ = $0$

Comment: Wait, If you plug $x = 0$ in $(n+1)(1+x)^n = \binom{n}0+2\binom{n}1x+3\binom{n}2x^2+...+(n+1)\binom{n}nx^n$, what do you get?

Comment: @AndreasCaranti We get $\binom{n}0$ or 1?

Comment: And the left-hand side?

Comment: @AndreasCaranti we get n+1 and they aren't equal unless n=0?

Comment: Right. Please check my answer.

Comment: $(n+1)(a+b+c+\ldots+z) = (n+1)a + (n+1)b +(n+1)c +\ldots+(n+1)z$ $\neq a + 2b + 3c+\ldots+(n+1)z$ in the general case, even when it does happen that $a = (1+x)^0, b = (1+x)^1, c = (1+x)^2, \ldots, z=(1+x)^n$.

Comment: You wrote $\sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^k(k+1)\binom{n}{k}=\sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^k(n+1)\binom{n}{k}$ which, interestingly, is true (since both are zero) but an incorrect assumption in a proof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $n \ge 1$.

Start with $$(1+x)^n=\binom{n}{0}+\binom{n}{1} x+\binom{n}{2} x^2+ \dots +\binom{n}nx^n.$$

Multiply by $x$ to get
$$
x (1+x)^n=\binom{n}{0} x+\binom{n}{1} x^2+\binom{n}{2} x^3+ \dots +\binom{n}{n} x^{n+1}.
$$
Differentiate to get
$$
(1 + x)^n + n x (1 + x)^{n-1}
=
\binom{n}0+2\binom{n}1x+3\binom{n}2x^2+ \dots +(n+1)\binom{n}nx^n.
$$
Now set $x = -1$. Note that the case $n = 1$ is special.

Comment: So is the answer still 0 or do we leave it in the general form: $(1+x)^n+nx(1+x)^{n-1}$?

Comment: Please try substituting $x = -1$ and see what happens. You get a special result for $n = 1$, and the general one for $n > 1$.

Comment: By setting $x=-1$, we get the original series on the right-hand side, but 0 on the left-hand side.

Comment: Right, except that for $n = 1$ LHS is $-1$. And thanks!

Answer (score 2):

More than that is true.
For any $a$ and $b$,
if $n \ge 2$,
$\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^k(ak+b)\binom{n}k
= 0
$.

If $n \ge k \ge 1$,
$k\binom{n}k
=k\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}
=\frac{n!}{(k-1)!(n-k)!}
=n\frac{(n-1)!}{(k-1)!(n-k)!}
=n\binom{n-1}{k-1}
$.

Therefore,
since,
for $n \ge 1$,
$\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^k\binom{n}k
=0$,
if $n \ge 2$ then

$\begin{array}\\
\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^k(ak+b)\binom{n}k
&=b+ \sum_{k=1}^n(-1)^k(ak+b)\binom{n}k\\
&=b+ \sum_{k=1}^n(-1)^k(ak\binom{n}k+b\binom{n}k)\\
&=b+ \sum_{k=1}^n(-1)^kak\binom{n}k+\sum_{k=1}^n(-1)^kb\binom{n}k\\
&= \sum_{k=1}^n(-1)^kan\binom{n-1}{k-1}+\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^kb\binom{n}k\\
&= an\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}(-1)^{k+1}\binom{n-1}{k}\\
&= -an\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}(-1)^{k}\binom{n-1}{k}\\
&=0\\
\end{array}
$

Answer (score 1):

A combinatorial evaluation is also possible. Let

$$f(n)=\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^k\binom{n}k(k+1)\;,$$

the sum in question. Then

$$\begin{align*}
f(n)&=\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^k\binom{n}{n-k}(k+1)\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^{n-k}\binom{n}k(n-k+1)\\
&=(-1)^n\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^k\binom{n}k(n+1-k)\;,
\end{align*}$$

and I’ll evaluate that last summation combinatorially.

As usual let $[n]=\{1,\ldots,n\}$, and let $A=[n]\cup\{0\}$; I’ll count the one-element subsets of $A$ that are equal to $\{k\}$ for each $k\in[n]$. For each $k\in[n]$ let

$$F_k=\big\{\{\ell\}:\ell\in A\setminus\{k\}\big\}\;;$$

if $\varnothing\ne J\subseteq[n]$, then

$$\left|\bigcap_{k\in J}F_k\right|=n+1-|J|\;,$$

so by the [inclusion-exclusion principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle#Statement) we have

$$\left|\bigcup_{k\in[n]}F_k\right|=\sum_{\varnothing\ne J\subseteq[n]}(-1)^{|J|+1}(n+1-J)=\sum_{k=1}^n(-1)^{k+1}\binom{n}k(n+1-k)\;.$$

This is the number of one-element subsets of $A$ that are different from at least one of the sets $\{k\}$ with $k\in[n]$. There are altogether $n+1$ one-element subsets of $A$, so there are

$$n+1-\sum_{k=1}^n(-1)^{k+1}\binom{n}k(n+1-k)=\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^k\binom{n}k(n+1-k)$$

one-element subsets of $A$ that are equal to $\{k\}$ for **every** $k\in[n]$.

If $n\ge 2$, this is obviously $0$, since a one-element subset of $A$ cannot be simultaneously $\{1\}$ and $\{2\}$. If $n=1$, it’s $1$: the only subset that meets the requirement is $\{1\}$. And if $n=0$, it’s vacuously $1$. Thus,

$$f(n)=(-1)^n\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^k\binom{n}k(n+1-k)=\begin{cases}
(-1)^0(1)=1,&\text{if }n=0\\
(-1)^1(1)=-1,&\text{if }n=1\\
(-1)^n(0)=0,&\text{if }n>1\;.
\end{cases}$$